# Quickly send file from phone to PC via internet?

Tags: sync, files, file-transfer

Is there a service/app that provide this functionality? I imagine the inversion of [Awesome Drop](http://labs.dashwire.com/drop).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A service like [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/android) should be able to do this for you. It'll sync the files up to the web, and then your PC (with Dropbox installed) should pull them down.

Comment: The usual caveat applies: "you are copying your files who-knows-where into the cloud, do you trust the file-sync provider?"

Answer (score 4):

[GTalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/) is able to send, browse and download files from your android phone via XMPP (gTalk). It's also a remote SMS notifier and has various other features.

Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved in GTalkSMS. GTalkSMS is an open source GPL licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.

Answer (score 2):

**Via email**

Well of course this works, but I hope there is a quicker, better, more straightforward way.

Answer (score 1):

With so many alternatives this days, the best options tends to be an application that allows us to work with multiple solutions.

[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) and the free version [FolderSync Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite), both by Tacit Dynamics available from Google Play Store, allows us to do just that:

> FolderSync enables easy sync of files between cloud storage and Android devices.
>
> FolderSync is a application that enables simple sync to cloud based storage to and from local folders on the device memory card. It currently support multiple SkyDrive, Dropbox, SugarSync, Ubuntu One, Box.net, LiveDrive, HiDrive, Google Drive, Google Docs, NetDocuments, Amazon S3, FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WebDAV or windows share (Samba/CIFS) accounts, and support for more platforms are planned.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) (Modular Android XMPP Suite) is able to exchange files over [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP).

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into MAXS. MAXS is an open source GPLv3 licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your Android device and the PC are in the same local network, e.g. connected to the same Wi-Fi access point or the same router/switch, and you have Total Commander installed + WiFi/WLAN plugin, then you simply long tap the > Send To > Send via Wi-Fi (Total Commander), and then enter the displayed URL in your browser. Or use the QR code if you want to share to another mobile device with a camera.

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way is this little software named Sego for me : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nex.sego

Comment: Could you explain why? And how to send files with this to a Mac or Linux PC?