# Application for automatic synchronization of remote folders?

Tags: sync, file-transfer, remote-control, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complete dropbox implementation for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/complete-dropbox-implementation-for-android)

I'm looking for an application that will synchronize folder automatically from my computer to Android device. Application should run in background.

I've tried Dropbox but it requires to manually download each file.

Any suggestions about such kind of Application on Android Market?

EDIT: For 'Remote' I mean my computer that is on the internet (not in the same network).

EDIT: Another key feature is that I want to synchronize my Folder with multiple Android devices.

EDIT: All suggested applications don't run continuous synchronisation from remote to local. Do you know any Dropbox implementation that will automatically download files from remote on Android device?

Comment: How remote are your remote folders? We've had a few previous questions on this sort of thing. Are you trying to sync to a PC on the same network as you?, to your home Pc via the internet, or up to a server on the internet? It seems like the answers on this question are closest to what you're after http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/ but there's also this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/ or this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/ or http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/ and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/complete-dropbox-implementation-for-android Covers pretty much what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

I use SugarSync. It does exactly what you are looking for and you get 5 gigs of storage on the free account.

Comment: I've used it but it requires manual synchronization. What client do you use?

Comment: @Matt: Referral links are not allowed in Stack Exchange.

Comment: I use sugarsync's app and it auto-syncs. I'll provide a link when I'm at the computer.

Comment: @Al: can you give me a link to some documentation on that? The FAQ seems to suggest under "May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?" that it is acceptable as long as its relevant and you're upfront about it.

Comment: @Matt: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75624/ban-dropbox-referral-affiliate-links http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/using-affliate-links-in-answer-question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/amazon-affiliate-tags

Comment: Thanks Al. The FAQ should be changed to reflect that sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) (Free lite version is also available with some limitations). It supports FTP, SFTP, FTPS, FTPES, WebDAVs etc. protocols to connect with remote computer. It has many sync options: Two-way sync, One-way sync (up or down).

And yes, it does sync automatically. You can set time intervals for syncing. Instant sync is also an option.