# Synchronize a folder in an Android device with a server folder

Tags: sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application for automatic synchronization of remote folders?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7763/application-for-automatic-synchronization-of-remote-folders)

How can I synchronize a folder in an Android device with a server folder? In other words, if in server a file is updated with the same name, then that file will also synchronize with the device.

Comment: You use service like Dropbox and Google Drive.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) (Free lite version is also available with some limitations). It supports FTP, SFTP, FTPS, FTPES, WebDAVs etc. protocols to connect with server. It has many sync options: Two-way sync, One-way sync (up or down).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the "cloud" services that have an Android app should work for you (e.g. [Box](https://www.box.com/) - [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.box.android), [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) - [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android), [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) - [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs), [SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/) - [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sharpcast.sugarsync), etc.)

However, keep in mind that most such 3rd-party services store your data on their own servers.  If you are conscious about sensitivity of your data and want more control over how and where it's stored, the off-the-shelf services may not be the solution for you.  You'll need to set up your own [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)/[WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV)/etc. server, and make it available online by modifying your network's firewall rules to allow outside connectivity.  If you have a dynamic IP address from your ISP, you'll also want to register with a free service like [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html) which gives your server a static URL and little Windows/Mac/Unix utility to keep the server's IP address in sync, so that it's always accessible.

You can then use a different kind of a sync app which allows for specifying address/type of the server to sync to.  Sachin's suggestion [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) will work perfectly for that.